# an array of functions of a class

Tags: c++

To store the functions of a class in an array the following link http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/cpp/1 contains the code like below (Machine is the class name).

```
void(Machine:: *ptrs[])() = 
  {
    Machine::off, Machine::on
  };
```

The example in that link does not compile with the g++ compiler throwing error as below

```
$ g++ state.cpp 
state.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
state.cpp:89:18: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Machine::off()’
state.cpp:89:32: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Machine::on()’
state.cpp:97:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘*’ token
```

I am using g++ version 4.5.2

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Can an array be defined like this, i am not able to find an array defination like this any where else. If the example is correct why does not it compile.

Comment: Are the member functions you are trying to place in the array static? if not, how do you expect them to work since they will be missing a *this* reference.

Comment: Read about pointers-to-member-functions.

Comment: ... Member function pointers aren't called alone - you just call them with a member of the class.  The function pointer is independent of the address of the class member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a [typedef for your member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.5) you will simplify your code greatly.

```
class Machine
{
public:
    void on(){}
    void off(){}
};


int main()
{

    typedef void (Machine::*MachineFunctionPtr)();

    MachineFunctionPtr temp[] = { &Machine::off , &Machine::on };


   //To invoke a function use this syntax
    Machine mymachine;
   ((mymachine).*(temp[1]))();
```

**The being said your error is due to missing "&" before the function name**.

If you don't want to [use typedef the correct way is something like](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.5)

```
void(Machine:: *ptrs[])() = 
{
    &Machine::off, &Machine::on
};
Machine fsm;
int num;
while (1)
{
    cout << "Enter 0/1: ";
    cin >> num;
    ((fsm).*(ptrs[num]))();
}
```

Comment: How to read the array MachineFunctionPtr(MachineFunction Ptr is a ptr to ..)

Comment: I tried adding & which does gives error while calling the functions of object Machine using the code , Machine fsm;(fsm. *ptrs[0])(); The error is $ g++ state.cpp 
state.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
state.cpp:97:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘*’ token. For the complete code please look at the following link http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/cpp/1

Answer (score 2):

To be able to add your member-function-pointers to your array you'll need to prepend their identifiers with the address-of operator `&`.

Example:

```
struct Obj {
  void func_1 () {}
  void func_2 () {}
};

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  void (Obj::* pointers[]) () = {
    &Obj::func_1, &Obj::func_2
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the more c++ way to do it :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  typedef void (A::*memfpt)();

    A() : arr( { &A::foo, &A::bar } )
    {}

  void foo()
  {
    std::cout<<"foo"<<std::endl;
  }
  void bar()
  {
    std::cout<<"bar"<<std::endl;
  }

  std::vector< memfpt > arr;
};

int main() {
    A a;

    for ( auto &it : a.arr )
    {
        (a.*it)();
    }
}
```

Instead of raw array, I used std::vector, and instead of that unspeakable abomination, I used [the typedef](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.5).

Your specific example doesn't compile because :

1. line 97 : `(fsm. *ptrs[num])();` should be `(fsm.*ptrs[num])();` - you need to remove that space, because calling a pointer to member function should be done using `.*` or `->*`
2. line 89 : `Machine::off, Machine::on` should be `&Machine::off, &Machine::on` because that is how you get pointer to member function.

Comment: could you please consider to explain why does the code in here http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/cpp/1 does not compile

Comment: @Talespin_Kit Edited question to answer to fix your compilation errors. Take a note that the compiler still spits out the warning about unused variables.